# mps430-gcc .run file not doing any thing

Tags: virtualbox, compiling, gcc

I am using ubuntu 14.04 64 bit on virtualbox on Windows 8.1 64 bit host.

I have to build some project and the project uses cmake system. I need to cross compile my project for Texas Instruments cc430f5137 and for this i require msp430 gcc.

I downloaded the msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-3.2.3.0.run file as mentioned [here](http://software-dl.ti.com/msp430/msp430_public_sw/mcu/msp430/MSPGCC/latest/index_FDS.html) .

when i downloaded then I did

```
sudo chmod +x msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-3.2.3.0.run
```

then when I type

```
./msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-3.2.3.0.run
```

or

```
sudo ./msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-3.2.3.0.run
```

nothing happens and I get a new line on terminal.

if I type

```
sh ./msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-3.2.3.0.run
```

or

```
sudo sh ./msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-3.2.3.0.run
```

then I get the following error

```
./msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-3.2.3.0.run: 1: ./msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-3.2.3.0.run: Syntax error: "(" Unexpected
```

Even if I double click the.run file from the files directory, nothing happens

i am new to linux and I am doing this for the first time. I have searched the internet but I haven't found anything useful.

Please help me in setting up the msp430 gcc tool chain

Thanks

My question is too specific to my need but please I don't want it closed flagged as too specific.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, I think the problem is not explicitly related to VirtualBox nor to the host system. I encountered this problem trying to run the 3.05.00.00 compiler installer on Ubuntu 14.04 64bits (not the full installer).

Seeing this post on TI forums (http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/compiler/f/343/t/421764), I installed all the CCS prerequisite (http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Linux_Host_Support_CCSv6#Ubuntu_14.04_64bit), rebooted the pc and it finally worked :

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libx11-6:i386 libasound2:i386 libatk1.0-0:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgtk-3-0:i386 libice6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libsm6:i386 liborbit2:i386 libudev1:i386 libusb-0.1-4:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libxt6:i386 libxtst6:i386 libgnomeui-0:i386 libusb-1.0-0-dev:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 unzip
```

Answer (score 0):

quoted from http://colotronics.blogspot.com/2014/08/msp430-toolchain-in-ubuntu-1404-with.html

```
cd ~
mkdir mspgcc_install
cd mspgcc_install
```

## Dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install patch ncurses-dev build-essential bison flex zlib1g-dev sed automake gawk mawk libusb-1.0.0 libusb-1.0.0-dev dos2unix srecord
```

## Downloads:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/mspgcc/files/mspgcc/DEVEL-4.7.x/mspgcc-20120911.tar.bz2
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/mspgcc/files/msp430mcu/msp430mcu-20130321.tar.bz2
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/mspgcc/files/msp430-libc/msp430-libc-20120716.tar.bz2
wget http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/binutils/binutils-2.22.tar.bz2 
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.7.0/gcc-4.7.0.tar.bz2 
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.2a.tar.bz2

wget http://sourceforge.net/p/mspgcc/bugs/_discuss/thread/fd929b9e/db43/attachment/0001-SF-357-Shift-operations-may-produce-incorrect-result.patch
wget http://sourceforge.net/p/mspgcc/bugs/352/attachment/0001-SF-352-Bad-code-generated-pushing-a20-from-stack.patch
```

## GDB patch download

```
wget -O gdb.patch https://sourceware.org/git/?p=gdb.git;a=patch;h=7f62f13c2b535c6a23035407f1c8a36ad7993dec
```

## Uninstall texinfo 5.x and install oldversion 4.x

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/texinfo/texinfo_4.13a.dfsg.1-10_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -r texinfo 
sudo dpkg -i texinfo_4.13a.dfsg.1-10_amd64.deb
```

## Extract

```
tar xvfj mspgcc-20120911.tar.bz2
tar xvfj binutils-2.22.tar.bz2  
tar xvfj gcc-4.7.0.tar.bz2  
tar xvfj gdb-7.2a.tar.bz2
tar xvfj msp430mcu-20130321.tar.bz2  
tar xvfj msp430-libc-20120716.tar.bz2
```

## Create build folders

```
mkdir build
cd build
mkdir binutils 
mkdir gcc
mkdir gdb 
cd ..
```

## Binutils install

```
cd binutils-2.22
patch -p1<../mspgcc-20120911/msp430-binutils-2.22-20120911.patch 
cd ../build/binutils 
../../binutils-2.22/configure --target=msp430 --prefix=/usr/local/msp430 2>&1 | tee co
make 2>&1 | tee mo
sudo make install 2>&1 | tee moi
```

## gcc

```
cd ../../gcc-4.7.0
patch -p1 < ../mspgcc-20120911/msp430-gcc-4.7.0-20120911.patch 
patch -p1< ../0001-SF-352-Bad-code-generated-pushing-a20-from-stack.patch 
patch -p1< ../0001-SF-357-Shift-operations-may-produce-incorrect-result.patch 
./contrib/download_prerequisites
#ira-int.h replace
cd gcc
rm ira-int.h 
wget -O ira-int.h https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/gcc-4_7-branch/gcc/ira-int.h?revision=191605&view=co&pathrev=191605

cd ../../build/gcc 
../../gcc-4.7.0/configure --target=msp430 --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix=/usr/local/msp430 2>&1 | tee co
make 2>&1 | tee mo

sudo make install 2>&1 | tee moi
```

## Update PATH

```
export PATH=/usr/local/msp430/bin/:$PATH
sudo sed -e '/^PATH/s/"$/:\/usr\/local\/msp430\/bin"/g' -i /etc/environment
```

## Check msp430-gcc, must return 4.7.0 20120322

```
msp430-gcc --version
```

## Install gdb

```
cd ../../gdb-7.2
patch -p1 < ../mspgcc-20120911/msp430-gdb-7.2a-20111205.patch
patch -p1< ../gdb.patch
cd ../build/gdb 
../../gdb-7.2/configure --target=msp430 --prefix=/usr/local/msp430 2>&1 | tee co 
make 2>&1 | tee mo
sudo make install 2>&1 | tee moi
```

## Check gdb installation:

```
msp430-gdb --version
```

## Must return 7.2

## msp430mcu and msp430-libc

```
cd ../../msp430mcu-20130321/
sudo MSP430MCU_ROOT=`pwd` ./scripts/install.sh /usr/local/msp430 | tee so

cd ../msp430-libc-20120716/src/
make 2>&1 | tee mo
sudo PATH=$PATH make PREFIX=/usr/local/msp430 install 2>&1 | tee moi 
cd ../..
```

Comment: Thanks but I think it is for mspgcc which has been depreciated by Texas Instruments and its not msp430-gcc which is the currect supported 
(it is the RHGCC 4.9)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Lubuntu 16.10 on a VM with Windows7 host and I first installed libc6:i386 and then executed, in my case, [msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-4.2.0.36.run](https://www.ti.com/licreg/docs/swlicexportcontrol.tsp?form_type=2&prod_no=msp430-gcc-full-linux-installer-4.2.0.36.run&ref_url=http://software-dl.ti.com/msp430/msp430_public_sw/mcu/msp430/MSPGCC/latest/) with terminal and it worked w/o installing CCS at all.

open terminal, you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> keys for that, and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```

Wait for it to finish, and then run your original commands for executing, or with gui double click and execute with terminal.